# Fighting against repetitive clicks

Tags: php

I'm writing an Adsense style adserver now. Want to know which are the best methods to fight against repetitive clicks. Now i'm storing the clickers IP address in an other table, and allow 1 click in every 24hr for an ad. This solution is not the best, and it still can be screwed. How does Google and the others does?

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I don't know exactly how google does it, but it's quite possible that people are behind NAT so many will share same IP address and you'll block all of the ones who haven't actually clicked. I'd datamine as much data as possible from the client - referer, browser identification and so on and by combining IP and mined info I'd try to identify a single user using such approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One click per 24h will hurt your business big time. Just think of big organizations with just one public IP for their "staff computers".

As far as I know, there is no proper solution to this, but a combination of these things might do the trick for you:

1. Check in your session if a click has already occurred.
2. Check against a cookie.
3. If using flash, check against a shared object.
4. IP-based limit (but probably much more lax than what you've got now).

Also up-voted Michael J.V's comment. Collecting data about the specific client (and store in database) will make much sense.

Of course, people can spoof that data, but I don't think you can do anything about that (except having a lax IP-based limit).

Answer (score 0):

My solution: Store a cookie + an IP etc.
Maybe even sessions are helpful.